# How to getdata from entry widgets with same name but in different frames

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, names

I've created sevearal frames and added labels & entry widgets etc to each frame, but I've named these label & entry widgets the same in each of the frames.
So how do I uniquely get the entry data from a "frame.entry"

i.e. below is all unique names which works OK:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

def get_b1():
    x = e1.get()
    if x == "":
        l1.configure(text = "Enter something")
    else: 
        l1.configure(text = x)
    
def get_b2():
    x = e2.get()
    if x == "":
        l2.configure(text = "Enter something")
    else: 
        l2.configure(text = x)
    
f1 = tk.Frame(master=window, relief=tk.RAISED, borderwidth=1)
f2 = tk.Frame(master=window, relief=tk.RAISED, borderwidth=1)

b1 = tk.Button(f1, text = "Press me", command = get_b1)
b2 = tk.Button(f2, text = "Press me", command = get_b2)

e1 = tk.Entry(f1)
e2 = tk.Entry(f2)

l1 = tk.Label(f1, text="I'm in frame 1")
l2 = tk.Label(f2, text="I'm in frame 2")

f1.grid(row=0, column=0)
f2.grid(row=1, column=0)

b1.grid( row=0, column=0)
e1.grid( row=0, column=1)
l1.grid( row=0, column=2)

b2.grid( row=0, column=0)
e2.grid( row=0, column=1)
l2.grid( row=0, column=2)
```

but if I rename the f2 widgets as b1, e1, l1 etc,
This fails miserably:
Does this mean widgets all have to have unique names, Ididn't think that was the case?

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

def get_f1_b1():
    x = e1.get()
    if x == "":
        l1.configure(text = "Enter something")
    else: 
        l1.configure(text = x)
    
def get_f2_b1():
    x = e1.get()
    if x == "":
        l1.configure(text = "Enter something")
    else: 
        l1.configure(text = x)
    
f1 = tk.Frame(master=window, relief=tk.RAISED, borderwidth=1)
f2 = tk.Frame(master=window, relief=tk.RAISED, borderwidth=1)

b1 = tk.Button(f1, text = "F1, Press me", command = get_f1_b1)
b1 = tk.Button(f2, text = "F2, Press me", command = get_f2_b1)

e1 = tk.Entry(f1)
e1 = tk.Entry(f2)

l1 = tk.Label(f1, text="I'm in frame 1")
l1 = tk.Label(f2, text="I'm in frame 2")

f1.grid(row=0, column=0)
f2.grid(row=1, column=1)

b1.grid(row=0, column=0)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
l1.grid(row=0, column=2)

b1.grid(row=1, column=0)
e1.grid(row=1, column=1)
l1.grid(row=1, column=2)
```

Comment: I think you are missing the idea of how variables/instances work. For example, these two lines: `e1 = tk.Entry(f1)` and `e1 = tk.Entry(f2)` create two entries, but variable e1 will only refers to the last entry (f2's entry), as you reset/reassign it.

Comment: OK, so EVERY entry, regardless of what frame it's in, has to be a unique name?

Comment: @KevP: yes, if you want to refer to the widgets via the variable. This is fundamental to programming, it's not something unique to tkinter or python.